# Storing password in Users table or Employees/Admin table

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, database, database-design

Let's say I have tables:

- employees
- administrators
- (maybe) users

Employees and Administrators have different columns (e.g. Department, Salary column only in Employees).

Where should I store the password? I'm using Laravel, so the Users table is already created when I initialized the project. I'm torn between storing the password in both the Employees and Administrators, or only in the Users table, but I have no idea how I should implement the relationships of the tables if I were to add the users table.

Comment: Sometimes it's necessary to distinguish between "authentication"/"credentials" and "identity". If you're storing the password in more than one place that's usually a sign you're confusing the two.

Comment: Are there non-employee users? Are administrators employees?

Comment: In this project I'm just assuming admins are not employees.

Comment: Can an employee or be an administrator, or are they mutually exclusive?

Answer (score 0):

I would probably keep the authentication associated with the users table, as per the default for laravel.

Here is an example of adding those relationships you would need.

```
// User model
public function employee()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Employee::class, 'user_id', 'id');
}

public function administrator()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Employee::class, 'user_id', 'id');
}

// Employee model
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id', 'id');
}

// Administrator model
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id', 'id');
}
```